# gtk3 change button bg color

Tags: c, gcc, gtk3

Today I start programming in GTK3, and I have a problem. I can't change the button background color, I want to change it after a click on the button. Here is my code:

```
void pushButton( GtkWidget* button )
{
    gtk_button_set_label( GTK_BUTTON( button ), "new_text" );
    GdkRGBA color = {.0, .0, .0, 1.0};
    gtk_widget_override_background_color ( button, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color );
}
```

gtk_button_set_label() is working well and changes the button label. But the color is still the same (should be black).

**gtk_widget_override_background_color has been deprecated since version 3.16 and should not be used in newly-written code. If you wish to change the way a widget renders its background you should use a custom CSS style.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add custom CSS to the Button:

```
GdkDisplay *display;
GdkScreen *screen;
display = gdk_display_get_default ();
screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);

GtkCssProvider *provider;

provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();

gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(provider, CSS, -1, NULL);

g_object_unref (provider);
```

Where you replace CSS with some CSS to modify the Button

Comment: Thanks. I try to use CSS, but that seems to be harder that use only function. They says, that function gtk_widget_override_background_color() is deprecated since version 3.16. There, in my Debian I have gtk 3.14, but gtk_widget_override_background_color() doesn't work. (Sorry for my English again!)

Comment: It is more difficult, but it also adds a lot of flexibility as you could create hover animations and so on...

Comment: Another thing would be that you set the name of the button with gtk_widget_set_name() so you can style only this button without affecting all other buttons in your application..

Comment: @mame98 I tried your solution and I can't figure how should work.I created a button and then I made `gtk_widget_set_name(button, "button1");` and inside the CSS file I have: `#button1 {
 background-color: black;
 color: black;

}` and it doesn't seems to work. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

I'll take another approach. The question is to change the bg color for one single button. Therefore I would only change it for this one single button. (I'm not sure about best practices, though).

- Add css
- Don't forget to set **`background-image:none`**, otherwise color settings have no effect
- Using a CSS class (in this case `*`, becuase the css is provided directly to the button (only). So *everything* (`*`) is only the button.

  ```
  void pushButton( GtkWidget* button )
  {
      // from your code
      gtk_button_set_label( GTK_BUTTON( button ), "new_text" );

      // You need an object to store css information: the CSS Provider
      GtkCssProvider * cssProvider = gtk_css_provider_new();
      // Load CSS into the object ("-1" says, that the css string is \0-terminated)
      gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(css, "* { background-image:none; background-color:red;}",-1,NULL); 

      // The "Style context" manages CSS providers (as there can be more of them)            
      GtkStyleContext * context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(button);   
      // So we want to add our CSS provider (that contains the CSS) to that "style manager".
      gtk_style_context_add_provider(context, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(css),GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);


      // I'm not sure, if you need this. I took it from mame89's code
      g_object_unref (css);  
  }
  ```

Although: **Be aware**, that this code will **create a new provider everytime** the button was pushed. I guess it's better practice to store the provider somewhere and removing and adding it to the (style)context when needed.